# how to count consecutive rows on a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive

I have a table having 3 columns.

Table Data

```
Customer_id   timestamp   page_url
1234     10-11-2015 10:00:12    page1
1234     10-11-2015 10:00:16   page3
1234     10-11-2015 10:00:19   page2
1234     10-11-2015 10:01:12   page1
1234     10-11-2015 10:01:20   page2   --- this should be counted as 1 
1234     10-11-2015 10:01:50   page2   --- this should be counted as 1
1234     10-11-2015 10:02:12   page4
5678     10-11-2015 09:11:12   page1
5678     10-11-2015 09:30:12   page3
5678     10-11-2015 09:50:10   page1
5678     10-11-2015 10:00:12   page2  -- this should be counted as 1
5678     10-11-2015 10:03:12   page3
```

Result : total count should be 3

Logic
i need the count where page 2 is visited by a customer just after page 1 according to the time stamp and if a customer has 2 page2 consecutive entries after page1 then should be counted as 2.

Need you help in writing a sql logic for the same.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using hive for this

Comment: Removed Teradata tag since your are using Hive.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this isn't the best solution but it works.

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (CustomerId NVARCHAR(4), Stamp DATETIME2, PageUrl NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:00:12','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:00:16','page3');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:00:19','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:01:12','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:01:20','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:01:50','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:01:53','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:01:55','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('1234','10-11-2015 10:02:12','page4');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 09:11:12','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 09:30:12','page3');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 09:50:10','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:00:12','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:12','page3');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:13','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:14','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:16','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:17','page2');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:18','page1');
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomerId, Stamp, PageUrl) VALUES('5678','10-11-2015 10:03:19','page1');

SELECT  CustomerId,
        Stamp,
        PageUrl,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CustomerId, Stamp) AS RowCnt
INTO #calls
FROM @tbl;

-- Selecting all calls of page2 where the previous page was page1 or page2
SELECT  tt.CustomerId,
        tt.Stamp,
        tt.PageUrl, 
        t.PageUrl AS PreviousPage,
        t.Stamp AS PreviousStamp,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerId ORDER BY t.CustomerId, t.Stamp) AS RowCnt
INTO #result
FROM #calls AS t
INNER JOIN #calls AS tt
    ON tt.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
    AND tt.RowCnt - 1 = t.RowCnt
    AND tt.PageUrl = 'page2'
WHERE t.PageUrl = 'page1' OR t.PageUrl = 'page2';


SELECT count(*) AS Result
FROM (
        -- Select all calls where the previous page was page1
        SELECT  CustomerId,
                Stamp,
                PageUrl, 
                PageUrl AS PreviousPage,
                Stamp AS PreviousStamp 
        FROM #result
        WHERE PreviousPage = 'page1'

        UNION ALL

        -- Select all calls of page2 where the previous page was page2 and the entry is in the result
        SELECT  tt.CustomerId,
                tt.Stamp,
                tt.PageUrl,
                tt.PreviousPage,
                tt.PreviousStamp
        FROM #result AS t
        INNER JOIN #result AS tt
            ON tt.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
            AND tt.RowCnt - 1 = t.RowCnt
            AND tt.PreviousStamp = t.Stamp
) AS result;

DROP TABLE #calls;
DROP TABLE #result;
```

Comment: It will work up to 1 consecutive page 2 but if there are more than 2 consecutive page 2, then how would i take the count

Comment: Sry for delayed answer... Do you mean with "2 consecutive page 2" this: page1, page2, page2? And if there would be page1, page2, page2, page2 it won't count the third page2?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for counting rows having distinct entries

```
select count(distinct(page_url)) from TABLENAME;
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for....i need to find the count based on the logic and also take into account the consecutive rows